# MariaDB external connection

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos7, firewall

[mariadb external connection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO1FQ.png)

Hello. I had this problem today
error Num 2003 can't connect to mysql server on '~~'.

I tried three methods, but failed. First, after connecting to mysql local, the grant option was added to the user.

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by 'abcd',
grant all privileges on *.* to 'user1'@'%' identified by 'abcd',
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

Second, I went to the /etc/my.cnf setting and set the bind address to 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, and even commented, but it failed.

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0,
bind-address = 1.1.1.1,
#bind-address = 1.1.1.1,
systemctl restart mariadb.service
```

Third, the mysql default port, 3306, was extended as a firewall.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

I have failed all three of these methods.
Someone please save me

Comment: The third 8080 is a typo and 3306 is correct.

Comment: The can't connect error message indicates that you need to figure out if it is the firewall or mysql settings (not user access rights) that prevent you from accessing your mysql. Unfortunately, none of these are related to programming, so you posted your question on the wrong site. Ask your question on the dedicated dba site.

Comment: Login local and execute ** select @@bind_address;** and see there are 0.0.0.0 I have seen a "," at the end of your my.cnf